# How to avoid html tags in edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 4 and I have used jquery text-editor. For omitting html tags, I have used sanitize helper.it's working fine.But edit the form shows html tags in description field.

form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @newsletter, html: {class: 'form-inline form-horizontal'}, :validate => true do |f|%>
<br/></br/><br/>
<div class="tabable well">
      <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active">
              <div class="inputs">
              <h4 class="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;">&emsp;<img src="/assets/side_menu/news-and-events.png" alt="Home" ></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add NewsLetter</h4><br/><br/>
              <div class="offset0">
                    <%= f.input :name %>
                    <%= f.input :description, as: 'text',   :input_html =>{:rows => '20', :cols => '180', :class => 'wysiwyg input-block-level' }%>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                    <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
                    <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Save
                    <% end %>
                        <%= link_to new_newsletter_path, class: 'btn btn-inverse' do %><i class='icon-hand-left'> Cancel</i><% end %>
            </div>  
      </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Edit Page

edit.html.erb

```
<%= render 'news/sidebar'%>
<%= link_to 'Back', newsletters_path, :class => 'btn btn-inverse animated rotateIn' %>      
<%= link_to 'View', newsletter_path(@newsletter), :class => 'btn btn-success animated rotateIn pull-right' %> 
<br><br>
<div class='row-fluid clear'>
    <div class='box gradient'>
        <div class=''>
            <%= render 'form' %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know , how to use sanitize in edit page. Please Guide Me..

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize

Answer (score 0):

it appears you are missing a closing `</div>`